# Why is Spring API returning 2 responses in the same request?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

This is something that started over the last 2 days. As far as my team knows, we have not made any changes that might have caused this.

My controller

```
@RestController
@Log4j2
@Api(value = "RegistrationController")
public class RegistrationController {

    @PostMapping("/edit-registration")
    public JsonResponse editRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody final RegistrationDTO registrationDTO) {
        log.info("Request received to edit registration");
        return JsonResponse.builder().httpStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                .data(this.RegistrationService.updateRegistration(registrationDTO)).build();
    }
}
```

*JsonResponse is a custom class that implements Serializable to construct the, well, Json response.*

My service

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class RegistrationService implements IRegistrationService {

    @Override
    public RegistrationDTO updateRegistration(@Valid final RegistrationDTO registrationDTO) {
        
        // business logic to verify and update registration
        
        return registrationDTO;
    }
}
```

Up until the last 2 days, this API was working fine, but then we started getting this response during SIT testing. It is only happening for this specific API, so I can safely rule out issues with the custom JsonResponse, which is used by all my other APIs and they aren't getting this.

[image: double response]

The first response returns with status 200 and the expected data, but then a second response is weirdly appended below. It's not even formatted correctly together with the first one to form a Json array. This is causing my frontend to go bonkers because it cannot parse the returned object correctly.

Tracing the logs, I see a StackOverflowException which we suspect is what is causing the second response to return with status 500 (which we are working on resolving). What we can't figure out is why there is even a second response in the first place.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Comment: Why are you using a custom JsonResponse builder class when springboot will automatically convert any rest endpoint response to json if you just return the pojo ? Also please attach the entire stacktrace with the question for analysis.

Comment: You simply cannot return 2 responses, it is one response. So apparently there is something else adding something to the response already. I suspect you have some global error handling which kicks in while or after the first part of the response has been sent.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan the JsonResponse class is mandated by our architect team. I never really got the full explanation why (some kind of custom security requirement?).

Comment: However, as @M.Deinum suspected, it had something to do with the global exception handling in our core libraries (done by that same architect team). The problem went away right after we fixed the StackOverflowException that was causing it. We still don't know how or why it happened the way it did (appending to a status 200 instead of overriding it), but at least now we can move on from it.

Comment: You cannot override an already send response, the only possibility is to append to it.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was that the exception message would have been sent as the response wouldn't it? I should have got a single status 500 response instead of this strange amalgamation of 2 different responses. You send one or the other, not both in the same response.

I guess I'm still struggling with picturing the steps that led to this. :(